# How to extract specific text from pdf files using pdfminer

Tags: python, extract, pdfminer

I am trying to extract this text using pdfminer(it's in indonesia language):

```
Uraian
Hasil pemeriksaan psikologis menunjukkan bahwa saudara/i IRSYAD MUHAMMAD SUMARNA memiliki keinginan yang tinggi untuk
melaksanakan tugas secara teratur dan menjaga barang serta ide secara sistematis. . Selain itu, saudara/i IRSYAD MUHAMMAD SUMARNA
memiliki kebutuhan yang tinggi untuk mengekspresikan dirinya dan memiliki kepercayaan diri yang tinggi serta memiliki kebutuhan yang
tinggi untuk mencapai suatu prestasi atau memiliki dorongan meraih sesuatu dalam hidup.

Namun, saudara/i IRSYAD MUHAMMAD SUMARNA kurang memiliki dorongan untuk melawan dan menahan diri untuk berperilaku agresif.
Selain itu, saudara/i IRSYAD MUHAMMAD SUMARNA tergantung pada orang lain dalam melakukan sesuatu termasuk dalam pengambilan
keputusan serta kurang menyukai situasi yang menuntutnya menjadi ketua kelompok atau yang mengatur orang lain serta kurang memiliki
kebutuhan untuk mempengaruhi orang lain, tidak terlalu suka menyalahkan diri sendiri, dan menyukai sesuatu yang tetap dan rutin dalam
diri dan kehidupan sehari-hari.
```

from this [pdf files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J9RvywidHVaT93mpwcAXDR_U6ltI6Xqh/view). I was able to convert from pdf folder that contains 10 pdf files to text using the code below:

```
from io import BytesIO
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
import os
import sys, getopt

#converts pdf, returns its text content as a string
def convert(fname, pages=None):
    if not pages:
        pagenums = set()
    else:
        pagenums = set(pages)

    output = BytesIO()
    laparams = LAParams()
    manager = PDFResourceManager()
    converter = TextConverter(manager, output, laparams=laparams)
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(manager, converter)

    filepath = open(fname, 'rb')
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(filepath, pagenums):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    filepath.close()
    converter.close()
    text = output.getvalue()
    output.close
    return text 

def convertMultiple(pdfDir, txtDir):
    if pdfDir == "": pdfDir = os.getcwd() + "\\" #if no pdfDir passed in 
    for pdf in os.listdir(pdfDir): #iterate through pdfs in pdf directory
        fileExtension = pdf.split(".")[-1]
        if fileExtension == "pdf":
            pdfFilename = pdfDir + pdf 
            text = convert(pdfFilename) #get string of text content of pdf
            textFilename = txtDir + pdf + ".txt"
            textFile = open(textFilename, "w") #make text file
            textFile.write(text) #write text to text file
            #textFile.close

pdfDir = "/home/a1-re/Documents/pdftotext/pdf/" 
txtDir = "/home/a1-re/Documents/pdftotext/Text/"
convertMultiple(pdfDir, txtDir)
```

the code above output this:

```
Aspek Kebutuhan

Kategori

KS

K

S

TS

4/5/2018

Hasil Pemeriksaan Psikologi

Hasil Psikotest

1831654 1831150002 MAULFI NATSIR ASYARI

Instansi Durasi Konsistensi

29 menit 11/15

Kode Ujian UPCM Nama   Psikogram

2 Deference 

3 Order 

4 Exhibition 

5 Autonomy 

6 Affiliation 

7 Intraception 

8 Succorance 

9 Dominance 

10Abasement 

11Nurturance 

12Change 

13Endurance 

14Heterosexual 

15Aggression 

1 Achievement 

Kemauan untuk menunjukkan adanya suatu prestasi

Kemauan untuk menyesuaikan diri dan mengikuti aturan

Kemauan untuk mengatur hidupnya, barang-barang, ide-ide dan tanggung jawab

Kemauan untuk mengkespresikan diri, optimistis, dan percaya diri

Kemauan untuk mandiri, dan tidak tergantung pada orang lain dalam hal pendirian/pendapat

Kebutuhan akan perhatian dari orang lain dan pergaulan yang harmonis

Kebutuhan untuk berempati dan bersimpati kepada orang lain

Kebutuhan untuk dimanjakan oleh orang lain

Kebutuhan untuk mendominasi, memerintah, dan mempengaruhi orang lain

Kebutuhan untuk mengakui kesalahan diri

Kebutuhan untuk menolong, merawat orang/ benda

Kebutuhan untuk melakukan perubahan

Kebutuhan untuk menyelesaikan sesuatu dengan tekun dan ulet

Kebutuhan terhadap kehidupan seksual

Kebutuhan untuk mendobrak sesuatu secara agresif

Uraian Hasil pemeriksaan psikologis menunjukkan bahwa saudara/i MAULFI NATSIR ASYARI memiliki kebutuhan yang tinggi untuk menyesuaikan diri dan mengikuti aturan/konvensi yang telah ditetapkan. Selain itu, saudara/i MAULFI NATSIR ASYARI memiliki kebutuhan yang tinggi untuk mencapai suatu prestasi atau memiliki dorongan meraih sesuatu dalam hidup serta memiliki kebutuhan yang tinggi untuk menolong dan merawat orang atau benda.

Namun, saudara/i MAULFI NATSIR ASYARI kurang memiliki dorongan untuk melawan dan menahan diri untuk berperilaku agresif. Selain itu, saudara/i MAULFI NATSIR ASYARI kurang menyukai situasi yang menuntutnya menjadi ketua kelompok atau yang mengatur orang lain serta kurang memiliki kebutuhan untuk mempengaruhi orang lain serta tidak terlalu suka menyalahkan diri sendiri, kurang menyukai keteraturan dalam bekerja dan cenderung kurang sistematis saat mengerjakan tugas, dan cukup tergantung pada orang lain dalam melakukan sesuatu termasuk dalam pengambilan keputusan.

Pemeriksa,

Uly Gusniarti, S.Psi., M.Si., Psikolog  0098-14-1-2

http://epps.tk/calculation/epps/1831654/print

1/1
```

How can I extract the specific text below from the PDF file? is there any easy way to convert the specific text?

```
Uraian Hasil pemeriksaan psikologis menunjukkan bahwa saudara/i MAULFI NATSIR ASYARI memiliki kebutuhan yang tinggi untuk menyesuaikan diri dan mengikuti aturan/konvensi yang telah ditetapkan. Selain itu, saudara/i MAULFI NATSIR ASYARI memiliki kebutuhan yang tinggi untuk mencapai suatu prestasi atau memiliki dorongan meraih sesuatu dalam hidup serta memiliki kebutuhan yang tinggi untuk menolong dan merawat orang atau benda.

    Namun, saudara/i MAULFI NATSIR ASYARI kurang memiliki dorongan untuk melawan dan menahan diri untuk berperilaku agresif. Selain itu, saudara/i MAULFI NATSIR ASYARI kurang menyukai situasi yang menuntutnya menjadi ketua kelompok atau yang mengatur orang lain serta kurang memiliki kebutuhan untuk mempengaruhi orang lain serta tidak terlalu suka menyalahkan diri sendiri, kurang menyukai keteraturan dalam bekerja dan cenderung kurang sistematis saat mengerjakan tugas, dan cukup tergantung pada orang lain dalam melakukan sesuatu termasuk dalam pengambilan keputusan.
```

Comment: Is your specific text has any pattern? or present at any specific Index? Can you tell more about *specific text*?

Comment: you can see the pdf file link above (I already edit it, so you can see it). In this pdf fle, I just want to extract the "Uraian" paragraph only. @shaikmoeed